# Efficiently draw combinations with "maximum diversity"

Tags: python-3.x, statistics, combinations

On can create all possible combinations with `n` elements from a given array like:

```
from itertools import combinations
[*combinations(range(4), 2)]
# [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

I'm trying to find a way to adapt this in order to find `m` of these combinations with "maximum diversity". What I mean by that is probably best explained by an example:

```
diverse_combinations(range(4), n=2, m=3)
# either of these would be what I'm looking for
# [(0, 1), (2, 3), (0, 2)]  # or
# [(0, 1), (2, 3), (1, 2)]  # or 
# [(0, 2), (1, 3), (0, 1)]  # ...
```

So I basically want the individual elements in the combinations of my subset to be as close uniformly distributed (or as close as possible). Therefore this is not quite what I want:

```
def diverse_combinations(arr, n, m): 
    for idx, comb in enumerate(combinations(arr, n)): 
        if idx == m: 
            break
        yield comb 

[*diverse_combinations(np.arange(4), n=2, m=3)]  
# [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3)]
```

Finally, the case I'm looking at is performance sensitive since it comes down to something like:

```
diverse_combinations(range(100), n=50, m=100)
# a list with 100 tuples of len=50 where each element appears 
# ~equally often
```

I'm glad for any hints!

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so I came up with this solution, which works reasonably well. I put it here in case its helpful for somebody else:

```
# python3
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import comb

def diverse_combinations(arr, size, count):
    if count > comb(len(arr), size):
        raise ValueError('Not enough possible combinations')
    possible_draws = np.floor(len(arr) / size).astype(int)
    combs = set()
    while len(combs) < count:
        new_combs = np.random.choice(
            arr, size=(possible_draws, size), replace=False)
        combs.update([tuple(sorted(cc)) for cc in  new_combs])
    return [*combs][:count]
```

Which gives a reasonable approximation of the desired behaviour:

```
# this case has an exact solution
np.unique(diverse_combinations(range(100), 50, 100), return_counts=True)[1]
# array([50, 50, 50, 50, 50,...

# here 50 elements appear one time more often   
np.unique(diverse_combinations(range(100), 50, 101), return_counts=True)[1]
# array([50, 50, 51, 50, 51,...

# if 'arr' is not divisible by 'size' the result is less exact
np.unique(diverse_combinations(range(100), 40, 100), return_counts=True)[1] 
# array([44, 45, 40, 38, 43,...
```